# Displaying and Saving the Best Trial During Hyperparameter Search with Optuna in Parallel GPU Environment

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, optuna

#### Issue

I am conducting hyperparameter optimization using Optuna integrated into the PyTorch Imagenet example (https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/imagenet/main.py), while parallelizing across GPUs. However, I am unsure how to display and save the results of the best trial (optimal trial).

#### Details

I am using the `study.optimize` method from Optuna as shown in the code below. `mp.spawn` is utilized to distribute the workload across each GPU. The issue arises in capturing and saving the results of the best trial while maintaining GPU parallelization. How can this be achieved?

```py
study.optimize(
    lambda trial: mp.spawn(
        objective, args=(ngpus_per_node, args, trial), nprocs=ngpus_per_node
    ),
    n_trials=100,
)

def objective(gpu, ngpus_per_node, args, trial):
    return main_worker(gpu, ngpus_per_node, args, trial)
```

#### Question

What is the recommended approach to display and save the best trial while performing hyperparameter search with GPU parallelization using Optuna? Is there a specific method or practice within Optuna or PyTorch that facilitates this?